# GRBM implementation

Tags: matlab, rbm

I am implementing Gaussian input based RBM in MATLAB.

`vi` has dimension of 100*784, `w` has dimension of 784*500, `sigma` has dimension of 1*784.

`p(h|v)= sigmoid(cj+wij*vi/sigma^2)`. I am getting dimensional error when I multiply `w*v/sigma^2`.
I have implemented it as below,

```
poshidprobspart = bsxfun(@rdivide,data,sigmas.^2);
poshidprobs = 1./(1 + exp(-((vishid * poshidprobspart) + repmat(hidbiases,numcases,1))));
```

What is causing the error in the code

Comment: Please include the full text of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part of the code `bsxfun(@rdivide,data,sigmas.^2)`, you need to align the matching non-singleton dimensions. In other words, if the size of `sigmas` is 1x784, and the size of `data` is 784x500, you need to match the 784 dimension. You probably want to transpose `sigmas`:

```
% bsxfun: 784x500 @rdivide 784x1 => 784x500
poshidprobspart = bsxfun(@rdivide,data,(sigmas.^2).');
```

Then `poshidprobspart` will be 784x500, which can then be multiplied: `vishid * poshidprobspart` if `vishid` is 100x784, resulting in a 100x500 matrix.

If `numcases` is 100 and `hidviases` is a row vector of length 500, then your code will run.

Comment: when i do that way, i got following error.Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Error in grbmcd (line 74)
  neghidprobspart1=bsxfun(@rdivide,negdata,(sigmas.^2)');

Comment: What is `size(negdata)` and `size(sigmas)`?

Comment: negdata size is same as data size, sigmas=1*784

Comment: Well, what is `size(data)`? 784x500? `bsxfun(@rdivide,negdata,(sigmas.^2)');` works fine if `negdata` is 784x500 and `sigmas` is 1x784

Comment: OK... so, do you understand my advice? You don't need to transpose everything in `neghidprobspart2=vishid'*neghidprobspart1';` if you instead transpose `sigmas` as long as `data`/`negdata`/whatever is 784x500.

Comment: but if i do transpose of sigma, i get error as i mentioned above.i told it works fine with the answer i mentioned

Comment: That's great, my point is `bsxfun(@rdivide,rand(784,500),rand(784,1))` works (try it!) so you can do it either way, you just need to make sure the arguments match.  Clearly `negdata` is not 784x500 (it must be 500x784).  That is what you would need to check. Your question does not at all make it clear the size of the variables, the names of which keep changing!

Comment: sorry for not making clear datasize and changing the name.Next time when i post i keep it in mind. it happens beacuse i was keep trying and changing in matlab and paste same here. I understand your point.thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works fine,if i implement in following way.

```
neghidprobspart1=bsxfun(@rdivide,negdata,sigmas.^2);
neghidprobspart2=vishid'*neghidprobspart1';
neghidprobs  =1./(exp(-(neghidprobspart2'+repmat(hidbiases,numcases,1))));
```

Comment: I'm guessing `negdata` is just `data'`. In that case, it's the same thing I'm suggesting.  Just align the non-singleton dimensions.